# Calling Methods in Infrastructure Project from Application layer in Clean Architecture C#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, clean-architecture

I am pretty new to [Clean Architecture in C#](https://jasontaylor.dev/clean-architecture-getting-started/).

Based on the details my understanding was all the business logic must be in Application Layer and any infrastructure level things (DB Crud operations, Message handlings) must be in infrastructure layer.

So I have started the development, but found there is no dependency with infrastructure layer in application layer. Even why they are saying keep the business logic in application layer and infra operations in that layer.

Without that dependency how can I access the CRUD operations in infra layer.

Also there is dependency with Applicaiton layer in infrastructure layer which is I didnt understand.

Someone please help because I really got stuck with it. I have few methods in my application layer and I need to write the output into DB as well, which I dont know how to implement.

So simple it would be like this based on the description

---

**Application Layer**

*IMessageBroker.cs*

```
Public class IMessageBroker
{
    Task<int> pushtoqueue(string queue, string message);
}
```

*myservice.cs*

```
public class myservice
{
   public void MyMethod
   {
      //Here I need to call the pushtoqueue method which I dont know
   }
}
```

---

**Infrastructure Layer**

*MessageBroker.cs*

```
public class messagebroker :Imessagebroker
{
   public task<int> pushtoqueue(string queue, string message)
   {
     // here the queue pushing code comes
   }
}
```

*DependencyInjection.cs*

```
services.Addscoped<IMessageBroker, MessageBroker>();
```

---

Please share your thoughts..

Environment

> .NET 6
>
> Azure Function Apps 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample you linked to uses a concept called "inversion of control" (IoC). Adapted to your sample and defined in a (lengthy) sentence, this concept is about inverting the dependency from the Application layer to the Infrastructure layer so that the Application layer defines its requirements towards the Infrastructure layer (in form of interfaces) and can work with any Infrastructure layer that implements these interfaces.

If you look at the diagram in the overview section, there is an arrow from the Infrastructure layer to the Application layer. This expresses the dependency from the Infrastructure layer on the Application layer.

In your case, the components serve the following purpuse:

- `IMessageBroker`: interface in Application layer that defindes the requirements that the Infrastructure layer has to fulfill.
- `MyService`: service class that uses infrastructure components. An instance of type `IMessageBroker` should be injected into the class in order to access the message broker.
- `MessageBroker`: concrete implementation of `IMessageBroker`.

The benefit of this approach is that you can easily replace infrastructure components without changing the application layer. While changing from one message broker to another might be comparatively seldom, being able to use mock objects when testing `MyService` is invaluable.

To answer the original question: how can you call the `pushtoqueue` method?

Just inject an instance of `IMessageBroker` into `MyService` and use it there:

```
public class MyService
{
  private readonly IMessageBroker _msgBroker;

  public MyService(IMessageBroker msgBroker) 
  {
    _msgBroker = msgBroker;
  }
 
  public void MyMethod
  {
    //Here I need to call the pushtoqueue method which I dont know
    _msgBroker.PushToQueue("queue", "message");
  }
}
```

In your sample, you already add a registration of `IMessageBroker` to the IoC container, so the instance is injected when creating `MyService`.

---

As a side note: following naming conventions increases readability for fellow programmers. I've changed some of the names from the question. For an overview of the C# naming conventions see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions).

Comment: Thanks a lot for such an awesome details... but just one confusion.. Here my service at application layer. So since application layer does not have any dependency with infrastructure, how can I inject that. Here MyService class and MyMethod method is where my business logic resides according to the Clean Architecture approach. Sorry if I wrongly interpreted..

Comment: @SandeepThomas you have a central IoC container, usually in an API project that registers the services (see `services.AddScope` in your question). This API knows that it wants to run on a specific infrastructure and therefore has a dependency to both the Application layer and the Infrastructure layer. When an API controller is constructed, it might use `MyService`, so the IoC container resolves the dependencies down the line.

Comment: Awesome.. Got you Markus.. Thank you very much...